# Using teamcity on a Project with multiple Mercurial Repos

Tags: .net, mercurial, teamcity

So why working on improving some of the development habits at the company that I work for I've decided to attempt to create a CI process using TeamCity. It was fairly straight forward until I got to the point where I was trying to set up my Build Agent to build a `.sln` that is comprised from about 11 mercurial repos (1 for each project).

So currently as I understand it and from what I can see in the TeamCity agent set up I point the agent to the repo to pull from to perform the build under the Create Build Settings tab I go to VCS Settings, at this point I can't seem to figure out how to get it to pull the changes from all of the repos that are associated with the `sln` file?

Am I going about this the wrong way or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeamCity can do that of course.

Go to a project "Edit Configuration Settings". Open "Version Control Settings". Click "Attach existing VCS root:" or "Create and attach new VCS root". You can add as many as you want VCS roots (aka repositories).

As far as I remember TeamCity will pull all repos into single directory.

I did same trick with my SVN repos. Worked fine.